# Downloading levels in UE4

Tags: unreal-4

I'm a total newbie to UE4. I need to make a game which downloads levels, actors, materials etc. every time it starts from the web. What is the best practice to do that? Is it possible using UE4 only or should I "wrap" it in something? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered just making your game HTML5? UE4 has an experimental option for HTML5 you can enable so it streams the levels on the fly.
[image]

Other options do exist, but they look pretty complex for beginners. [Here's One](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/109485/stream-an-asset-from-the-internet.html#answer-109555)